# Angular 7 - Services with event / observable subscription in constructor and call of abstract method

Tags: angular, events, service, observable, code-injection

Imagine the following situation:

You'd like to implement an Angular service that should exist in two fashions: One that uses a REST endpoint and another one that works as a mock without having the dependency to an endpoint. The REST service should be used in a production environment while the mock is used in development.

As both implementations have a lot of common, both extend from an abstract class. As the service (it doesn't matter which concrete implementation) should be invoked based on some incoming events, the respective subscription is placed in the abstract super class' constructor.

```
abstract class AService {

  constructor(someServiceEmittingEvents) {
      someServiceEmittingEvents.subscribe(() => {
         this.doSomething();
      });
  };

  abstract doSomething(): void;
}

class RestService extends AService {
  constructor(someServiceEmittingEvents, private httpClient: HttpClient) {
    super(someServiceEmittingEvents);
  }

  doSomething(): void {
     this.httpClient.post(...);
  }
}

class MockService extends AService {
  constructor(someServiceEmittingEvents) {
    super(someServiceEmittingEvents);
  }

  doSomething(): void {
    ...
  }
}
```

*Please consider the block of code as pseudo-syntax.*

When the RestService is provided, it happens from time to time that an event is emitted and dealt with while the service itself is "in construction". This results in the method `doSomething` being called in RestService while the HttpClient has not been assigned, thus being undefined as `doSomething` is called.

At least that's what it looks like when the constructor and method calls are logged and it sounds feasible to me.

As Angular services do not have lifecycle hooks as components do I'd like to ask what an appropriate way would be.

Answer (score 1):

I would generally avoid to subscribe to anything in a constructor. It tends to lead to situations like this.

I'd recommend you put your `someServiceEmittingEvents.subscribe` into a separate `init()` method (or something alike). Call that method from your components' `ngOnInit()` methods. Like that, you can be sure that the service (and its possible consumers) have been constructed before the observable is subscribed to.

The dirty alternative is to wait for the next tick before calling `someServiceEmittingEvents.subscribe` (using something like `setTimeout` or `setImmediate`). However, that's really just a workaround I would not recommend.